# Spring Cloud Stream ignores authentication settings

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm developing a simple microservice that is consuming messages from Kafka's topic and producing modified messages to another topic

Without an authentification all works perfectly. But when I'm tring to use SASL Plaintext authentification broker is writing  authentication errors to log. It looks like what auth settings were ignored, I get the messages in the application log during startup

```
...
    sasl.jaas.config = null
....
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
...
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
```

Here my application.yml file. I used this [github](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/main/multi-binder-samples/kafka-multi-binder-jaas/src/main/resources/application.yml#L25) file as an example.

```yaml
spring.cloud:
  function.definition: stocksProcessor
spring.cloud.stream:
  bindings:
    stocksProcessor-in-0:
      destination: input-stocks
      group: ms-pos-stocks-provider-dev
    stocksProcessor-out-0:
      destination: output-stocks.pretty
  kafka.streams:
    binder.applicationId: ms-pos-stocks-provider
  kafka.binder:
    brokers: kafka-01:19092,kafka-02:29092, kafka-03:39092
    jaas.enabled: true
    configuration.security.protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
    configuration.sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
    configuration.sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="user" password="password";
  kafka.bindings:
    stocksProcessor-in-0:
      consumer:
        enableDlq: true
        dlqName: dlq-stocks
        configuration:
          value:
            deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
    stocksProcessor-out-0:
      producer:
        compression: lz4
        configuration:
          value:
            serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

And here snippet from my pom.xml

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Thank you

Comment: It might be related to this (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2673) which is fixed in the next release (4.0.3). The work around is to put the security properties under Boot's global `spring.kafka` namespace instead of in the binder configuration.

Comment: @GaryRussell, yes! I've added as you suggest and it works!
Thank you very much :)